# Determine when the platform offers LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: environment-variables, path, linker

I want to detect when the platform offers `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to load libraries from an arbitrary location. The application is a lightweight shell script, so I am looking for a method that does not require compiling, linking and running a program.

I'm trying to avoid compiling a fake program and fake shared object and then attempting to run them. I'm also trying to avoid tests like `test "$IS_LINUX_OS"` and `test "$IS_SOLARIS_OS"`, but I will fall back to it if I have to.

I performed a search of the Open Group site but I did not find hits for Posix related path functions or environments.

Is there a quick and portable test to determine if the platform supports `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the systems that *don't* support LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but you can very quickly detect the presence of that symbol in the GNU libc loader with

```
grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH /lib/ld-*.so*
```

(that .so file is the one responsible for reading LD_LIBRARY_PATH and loading the rest of the libraries needed for a program)

Comment: Thanks. Won't that miss systems that do support `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, like AIX and Solaris? It might miss some Linux, like Fedora on 64-bit hardware because Fedora uses `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: AIX uses `LIBPATH`